# Response time differs based on where you execute the query from

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table structure in dynamo db with two fields. Partition key is a string (say Key). The second field is a Number Set (say Values).

I have a batch_get_item query on the Partition Key. The response time when i execute the command from AWS CLI is different from when I execute it from an AWS Lambda function.

The query response includes the Number Set. The Number Set can contain 30000 elements.

How can I test the true response time, are there any tools/best practices to test your response times. Also currently the response time is 0.3 seconds how can I take it to milliseconds, by increasing the read capacity? Or since I have sets of 30000 elements the response time cannot be reduced?

Comment: A significant factor in response time is where you are testing from, physically... are you testing with the CLI from inside EC2?  The CLI will have startup overhead that Lambda functions would not, after the lambda container has initialized everything.  How do these compare?  Where are you seeing the ~300ms responses, now?  Test on small responses, then work upwards, since a larger response necessarily requires more time.  I think more detail may be needed before a good "answer" can be written.

Comment: No I am testing it from my laptop. The 300 ms response is on Lambda. I will do as you say and test with various configurations (memory, number of items returned) and will update the question with those details.

Comment: 300ms response time as measured and reported by Lambda, or as measured from your laptop?